# detect selected list with specific value

Tags: jquery, select, attr

I would like to detect dropdown lists on my page that the user didn't change their values.
For this goal, I am trying to search for all the dropdown lists that the defaul value is still selected.

```
var t =  $("select[value='Select Team'] select:selected").attr("id");
alert(t);
```

> The alert is: 'undefined'

HTML code:

```
 <TMPL_LOOP DATA_ROLES>
        <tr id="<TMPL_VAR ID>">
            <td><select class="role2" id="role2_<TMPL_VAR ID>" name="role2_<TMPL_VAR ID>" title="The role of the employee"><TMPL_VAR ROLE></select></td>
            <td><input class="steps" id="steps_<TMPL_VAR ID>" type="text" name="steps_<TMPL_VAR ID>" size="5" title="Total amount of steps per month" value="<TMPL_VAR STEP>"></td>
            <td><input class="measurable_steps" id="measurable_steps_<TMPL_VAR ID>" type="text" name="measurable_steps_<TMPL_VAR ID>" title="Measurable steps" value="<TMPL_VAR MEASURABLE_STEP>"></td>
            <td><input class="steps_ratio" id="steps_ratio_<TMPL_VAR ID>" type="text" name="steps_ratio_<TMPL_VAR ID>" title="'Measurable steps' / 'Steps'" value="<TMPL_VAR STEPS_RATIO>%" readonly></td>
            <td style="text-align: center"><select class="reopen_rate" id="reopen_rate_<TMPL_VAR ID>" name="reopen_rate_<TMPL_VAR ID>" title="How many reopenes after closing the SI"><TMPL_VAR REOPEN></select></td>
            <td><select class="w4p" id="w4p_<TMPL_VAR ID>" name="w4p_<TMPL_VAR ID>"><TMPL_VAR W4P></select></td>
            <td><select class="team" id="team_<TMPL_VAR ID>" name="team2_<TMPL_VAR ID>"><TMPL_VAR TEAM></select></td>
            <td><input class="checkbox" id="checkbox_<TMPL_VAR ID>" type=checkbox></td>
            <td><input class="status2" id="status2_<TMPL_VAR ID>" type="hidden" name="status2_<TMPL_VAR ID>" value="<TMPL_VAR STATUS>"></td>
        </tr>
</TMPL_LOOP>
```

Can you please assist?

Thanks!

Comment: will you please put your html of your `select` tag

Comment: Have you tried `select[value='Select Team']:selected`

Comment: did your read my answer did it helped?

Comment: doesn't work - added the html...

Comment: my case look like: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/BFMD4/3/) http://jsfiddle.net/BFMD4/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<select value='Select Team' id='select'>
    <option id='1'>1</option>
    <option id='2'>2</option>
    <option id='3' selected >3</option>
    <option id='4'>4</option>
</select>


var t =  $('option[value='+$("#select").val()+']').attr("id");
alert(t);
```

Also u can get like this

```
var t =  $("select option:selected").attr("id");
alert(t);
```

U can try here http://jsfiddle.net/BFMD4/1/

Comment: it doesn't works: `var t =  $('option[value='+$(".team").val()+']').attr("id");` - added the html code...

Answer (score 0):

An `Option` object has `defaultSelected` property which is true if the option is initially selected (as in your case). All you need is to check if selected option is `defaultSelected` at the same time.

```
var $notChanged = $('select').filter(function () {
        return $(this).find('option:selected').get(0).defaultSelected
    });

// $notChanged is populated with selects that are not changed
```

Your case: http://jsfiddle.net/BFMD4/4/

That is if you want to find those that are not changed since the page load.

But if you want to test for a specific value you have other options.

**First: If you can use `values` in you `option` elements:**

```
<select>
    <option>Please select one...</option>
    <option value="apples">Apples</option>
    <option value="oranges">Oranges</option>
    <option value="ponies">Ponies</option>
</select>
```

Then to need to check if `select` has a value other than blank value.

```
var $notChanged = $('select').filter(function () {
            return $(this).val() === ''
        });
// the $notChanged collection contains unchanged select lists
```

**Second: If you absolutely must, as in your case, use id's to store value instead of `value` attribute**

You can add a class (e.g. "initial") to the option you want to be your initial option:

    Please select one...
    Apples
    Oranges
    Ponies

Then you look for these like this:

```
var $notChanged = $('select').filter(function () {
        return $(this).find('option.initial:selected').length > 0
    });
```

Comment: It looks good but not realy helpfull for me because if the initial value is other then 'Select Team' (i.e. team1, team2, team3) then it OK for me - I wish to find only the cases where the initial value is 'Select Team' (without the each statement if possible).